# NodeJS: Getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I'm reading emails from a csv file line by line and sending email to those emails

```
const emails = await readingCsvFile('emails.csv'); 
//readingCsvFile  returns all emails in an array

let promises = emails.map(async list => {
  try {
    return await sendEmail(list);
  } catch (err) {
   // Handle error
  }
});

await Promise.all(promises);


async function sendEmail(list) {
 await processEmail();
}


function processEmail() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
// Using SES with nodemailer
 }).then(function (response) {
resolve(1)
 }).catch(function (err) {
reject(1)
 })
}
```

but sometimes getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" for more email records any idea why I'm getting this and what's the solution

Comment: You left the stack trace out of the error message. Please include the full error.

Comment: How can you send email to emails?

Comment: In `processEmail()` `resolve(1)` and `reject(1)` are not in scope.